# onclick event does not get triggered after onchange

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Steps to recreate this issue:

1. Type something in the text box
2. Right after typing click the button.
3. I found that only onchange event was triggered.

Code:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" onchange="console.log('onchange');$('#message').css('display','none');" >
    <div id="message">
        Validating
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="console.log('onclick');" value="click me">
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQLFt/)

Comment: If you move the button away from under the div you remove, it works http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/edR2E/

Comment: When I try it in Chrome 24 Mac, I get both events logged.

Comment: `<input type="text" onchange="setTimeout(function(){ console.log('onchange');$('#message').css('display','none'); }, 250);"/> <input type="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ console.log('onclick'); }, 250);" value="click me"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `onclick` it is necessary to occur `mouse-down` and `mouse-up` event due to position change of your button its not calling `onclick`

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/zQLFt/4/) for complete event.

Comment: I put the button before the input box and then adjust the button to the position I want using css. It's working now. Thank you guys:)!

Answer (score 5):

Its because you are changing the layout which changes the button position and the button mouseup event is not getting called. 
See Demo:

**[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uhovag/1/)**

if you want to hide the div, by preserving the space it occupies, use:

```
$('#message').css('visibility','hidden');
```

**[New Demo with visibility hidden](http://jsbin.com/uhovag/4/)**

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. but any idea on how to fix it? In my website, the button can't be moved up to the text box.

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply! But I can't use it this way, because our customer require the validation message and the place to be totally invisible. So I have to use the "display" property.

Comment: You can change the position of your div to the right of input

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for keydown/press/up ...

The onkeydown event occurs when the user is pressing a key (on the keyboard)....

```
<div>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="console.log('onchange');$('#message').css('display','none');" >
    <div id="message">
        Validating
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="console.log('onclick');" value="click me">
</div>​
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zQLFt/1/

Answer (score 0):

The click event is combination of 2 events mousedown and mouseup. You can use mousedown instead.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" onchange="console.log('onchange');$('#message').css('display','none');" >
    <div id="message">
        Validating
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onmousedown="console.log('onclick');" value="click me">
</div>
```